# TypeError: 'float' object is not callable error while calling a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the code I currently have:

```
def uniform_distribution(users,radius):
   user_coordinates_distance=[]
   user_coordinates=[]
   finding_shadowing=[]
   r=radius*np.sqrt(np.random.uniform(0,1,users))
   angle=2*np.pi*np.random.uniform(0,1,users)
   x = r*np.cos(angle)
   y = r*np.sin(angle)
   user_distance = np.sqrt(x*x+y*y)
   x_shadowing=1000*x
   y_shadowing=1000*y
   x_shadowing=(x_shadowing-x_shadowing%10)/10
   y_shadowing=(y_shadowing-y_shadowing%10)/10
   finding_shadowing=shadowing(x_shadowing,y_shadowing,shadowing_matrix)
   print(finding_shadowing)
   for i in range (0,users):
       user_coordinates=[x[i],y[i],user_distance[i],finding_shadowing[i]]
       user_coordinates_distance.append(user_coordinates)    
   return (user_coordinates_distance)
```

And this is the error I get when I run it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ajit\Desktop\maryland\Sem 2\ENTS 656\project656\main program and functions\main_1.py", line 136, in <module>
    user_coordinates=uniform_distribution(attempts,cell_radius)#list [x,y,distance,shadowing]
  File "C:\Users\Ajit\Desktop\maryland\Sem 2\ENTS 656\project656\main program and functions\main_1.py", line 81, in uniform_distribution
    finding_shadowing=shadowing(x_shadowing,y_shadowing,shadowing_matrix)
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

What exactly does this error mean?

Comment: The error message is pretty self explanatory, no? You are trying to call a `float` object but float objects are not callable: `shadowing(x_shadowing,y_shadowing,shadowing_matrix)` so I can only surmise that `shadowing` is a `float`, but it's not actually defined above so it's some global object as far as I can tell.

Comment: Word to the wise: adding "help ASAP" to a question does not go down very well. This isn't a code debugging service.

Comment: Yes, shadowing_matrix is a global object holding a float value. The main loop calls this function uniform_distribution(users,radius), but when  finding_shadowing=shadowing(x_shadowing,y_shadowing,shadowing_matrix) is called first time there is no error, and when its called second time due to iteration from main loop this error comes.

Comment: Error is coming when this function is called twice? Any clue whats happening wrong?

Comment: Why are you trying to call a `float`??? And I wasn't talking about `shadowing_matrix` but about `shadowing`. See, you are calling whatever object that is referring to: `shadowing(...`

Comment: By the way, this is a good example of why relying on global state is a bad idea... it makes debugging a huge headache. Referential transparency makes your job easier.

Comment: Shadowing is an another function defined, its not a float.

Comment: Yes, it *is a float*. That is why your error is occurring. It says it right there in the error message. You've probably assigned some `float` value to the global variable `shadowing`. Indeed, you've *shadowed* `shadowing`... clearly that is happening somewhere in-between your first and second function calls. Again, this is why you shouldn't rely on mutable global state.